Bipolar 15 V DC from 9 V DC
I’m looking to get a regulated ±15 V DC @100mA minimum from a 9 V DC source. It’s for an audio circuit, so it needs to have a switching frequency well above audio range, and it needs to have a small total footprint.
From my research, the LT3471 seems like a good candidate for my purposes, and the attached application note seems like a good starting point. I’m wondering how to adjust this schematic to get the bipolar 15 V from 9 V or if there’s a better solution available. Thanks.
Datasheet.


What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you read the chapters in the data sheet on how to calculate the component values needed?

LT has some of the best datasheets out there, with detailed analysis of how the circuit works and how to calculate each parameter. Did you read the datasheet yet?

What are your noise/ ripple requirements?

Just a side question. Is the 9 V source an alkaline 9 V battery? (Just want to get rid of that issue, hoping it isn't true.)

See page 6 of the datasheet (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3471fb.pdf), the section entitled "Setting Output Voltage".  "Noninverting" means positive output, "inverting" means negative.  R1 and R2 are the relevant values for the positive output (matching R1 and R2 in the datasheet), R3 and R4 for the negative (matching R2 and R1 respectively in the datasheet).
